# Firebase verifyIdToken + NodeJS Express Authentication design

Tags: swift, express, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Problem:**
Due to legislation I **have** to store personal information within the EU (Social security number). Therefore I can't store this information in Firebase since there is no guarantee of geographical datacenter location when using Google's cloud services.

**My proposed solution:**
Having a Redis key value store with the sensitive information that can be accessed via a simple REST api where user authentication would be achieved using the users ID token, sent via HTTP Headers.

Firebase allows for verification of a user via the `verifyIdToken` method in the NodeJS library. This would allow me to check if the user ID matches any user id in my `/admin` end point of my Firebase. (Or I could hardcode the userIDs that would be allowed into the server since there aren't that many.)

So, the flow of the request would be as follows:

- User signs in client side using the Firebase SDK.
- Whenever the user needs access to the sensitive information it first gets the user's ID token

  ```
  let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
  currentUser?.getTokenForcingRefresh(true) {idToken, error in
    if let error = error {
      return
    }
    let headers = [
       "X-FBUser-Token":idToken
    ]
    //build request here to https://myServer.com/myEndpoint
  }
  ```
- Then server side we would retrieve the request

  ```
  app.get('/myEndpoint', function(req, res) {
    let idToken = req.get('X-FBUser-Token')

    verifyToken(idToken, function(isAdmin){
      if (isAdmin) {
        //Fetch the key value pair and send it back to the client here
      }
    })
  })

  function verifyToken(idToken, cb) {
    firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(function(decodedToken) {
      var uid = decodedToken.sub;

      firebase.database().ref('admins/' + uid).on('value', function (snap){
        cb(snap.val() !== null)
      })
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle error
    });
  }
  ```
- And then the client would receive back the response and deal with it. Everything done over HTTPS ofcourse.

*Note: I know that the code above is rather crude and would need some refinement, but hopefully you get the concept*

**My questions:**

- First of all, is this a **safe** way of doing things?
- Is there a better, more straight forward approach?